# How to find closest point to grid values

Tags: python, numpy, interpolation

I'm trying to interpolate the value of a function at a single point from it's nearest neighbors.

I have f specified on a meshgrid, `[x_grid,y_grid,z_grid] = np.meshgrid(x_range,y_range,z_range)`, for which I'd like to find an approximate value of a random point `p_rand = (x_rand, y_rand, z_rand)`.  What is an efficient way to find the indices of that nearest grid points and interpolate it's value?  It's in 3D - nearest cube or tetrahedron of points would be fine.

Comment: `scipy` has nearest-neighbor interpolators.

Comment: Those interpolators create a search tree  with your 'range' values, which can then can called repeatedly with the 'rand' values.  Once the tree is created the interpolation (lookup) is supposed to be quite fast.

Comment: like @hpaulj said, `scipy`'s implementation of nearest neighbour interpolator uses a native C backend of spatial tree, with the option of parallelisation. The performance actually is pretty good.

Comment: @CongMa So I just tried calling `interpolate.griddata(original_points,original_data, random_point)` twice in a row (as I thought hpaulj was suggesting) but it's not much faster.  How do I reuse the interpolated grid so it's just evaluating a handful of times around the random point?

Comment: Have you tried [`scipy.interpolate.NearestNDInterpolator`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.NearestNDInterpolator.html#scipy.interpolate.NearestNDInterpolator)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To expand on the comments of @hpaulj and mine...  The class you're looking for is [`scipy.interpolate.NearestNDInterpolator`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.NearestNDInterpolator.html)

This class is based on `scipy`'s own [`scipy.spatial.cKDTree`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.cKDTree.html).  The `cKDTree` class implements the [k-dimensional space-partition tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-d_tree), or "k-d tree" data structure, which trades construction time and space for fast search.

To use `scipy.interpolate.NearestNDInterpolator`, you initialise an instance like

```
from scipy.interpolate import NearestNDInterpolator
interpolator = NearestNDInterpolator(your_points, your_values_on_the_points)
```

After creating `interpolator`, use it to evaluate the interpolant value at `random_point` by

```
interpolant = interpolator(random_point)
```

Once created, `interpolator` can be reused for different input points, which is a Good Thing (tm).  You can also evaluate the interpolant value for multiple points by passing all of them into the call. [1]

If you look at the [source](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v0.16.0/scipy/interpolate/ndgriddata.py#L22), you'll discover how the interpolator is implemented using `cKDTree`.

[1] Actually there's a potential optimisation: if you need "vectorised" evaluation for many points, the underlying `cKDTree`'s `query()` method [supports parallelisation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.cKDTree.query.html#scipy.spatial.cKDTree.query), done in native C code running in threads.  Although `scipy`'s own implementation of `NearestNDInterpolator` doesn't use this feature, probably catering to greatest common divisor, you can override this by making your own subclass that uses parallelisation with a suitable choice of `n_jobs` parameter.

Note: the really good thing about using a k-d tree based interpolator is that its application can be extended to a "grid" in arbitrary shape (not necessarily rectangular).

---

**EDIT**:

Oh, so you meant to use the *nearest neighbors* for *linear* interpolation?

Then very sorry, I **misread your question**!

But then, you have two choices.

1. If your grid is sufficiently regular, and its construction (starting value / ending value / step known to you in all dimensions), it is not hard to write a function `findneighbor()` that locates the neighbors given the query point's coordinates.  Then you do the vanilla linear interpolation.
2. If your "grid" is not very regular, and you just have a lot of grind point coordinates (which may not lie on rectangular lattices), you can still use `scipy.spatial.cKDTree` to locate `N` nearest neighbors (possibly `N = 1 + (dimension of the grid)`).  After that, you interpolate on that `N` points.

Comment: well... I'm a bit resistant to doing nearest interpolation, but it is waaaay faster than linear interpolation.  Thanks!

Comment: @anon0909 I guess the doc assumes familiarity with k-nearest neighbor in general.  If you feel this can be improved, you can file an issue to `scipy`.