# Efficiently find indices of nearest points on non-rectangular 2D grid

Tags: python, performance, numpy, scipy, interpolation

I have an irregular (non-rectangular) lon/lat grid and a bunch of points in lon/lat coordinates, which should correspond to points on the grid (though they might be slightly off for numerical reasons). Now I need the indices of the corresponding lon/lat points.

I have written a function which does this, but it is REALLY slow.

```
def find_indices(lon,lat,x,y):
    lonlat = np.dstack([lon,lat])
    delta = np.abs(lonlat-[x,y])
    ij_1d = np.linalg.norm(delta,axis=2).argmin()
    i,j = np.unravel_index(ij_1d,lon.shape)
    return i,j

ind = [find_indices(lon,lat,p*) for p in points]
```

I'm pretty sure there's a better (and faster) solution in numpy/scipy. I've already googled quite a lot, but the answer has so far eluded me.

Any suggestions on how to efficiently find the indices of the corresponding (nearest) points?

**PS:** This question emerged from [another one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32845601/4419816)).

Comment: In your script, you're creating a new tree with each call to `find_indices`.  If your grid is fixed across calls, you're wasting time constructing the same tree over and over again.  Actually the construction of this tree is the single slowest call in this function.

Comment: Yes, I've noticed, it's what I'm working on at this very moment. ;) I'll update the answer accordingly. Thanks for the remark.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the points are sufficiently localized, you may try directly `scipy.spatial`'s `cKDTree` implementation, as discussed by myself [in another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32594456/how-to-find-closest-point-to-grid-values/32595450#32595450).  That post was about interpolation but you can ignore that and just use the query part.

tl;dr version:

Read up the documentation of [`scipy.sptial.cKDTree`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.cKDTree.html#scipy.spatial.cKDTree).  Create the tree by passing an `(n, m)`-shaped `numpy` ndarray object to the initializer, and the tree will be created from the `n` `m`-dimensional coordinates.

```
tree = scipy.spatial.cKDTree(array_of_coordinates)
```

After that, use `tree.query()` to retrieve the `k`-th nearest neighbor (possibly with approximation and parallelization, see docs), or use `tree.query_ball_point()` to find all neighbors within given distance tolerance.

If the points are not well localized, and the spherical curvature / non-trivial topology kicks in, you can try breaking the manifold into multiple parts, each small enough to be considered local.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a generic vectorized approach using [`scipy.spatial.distance.cdist`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.cdist.html) -

```
import scipy

# Stack lon and lat arrays as columns to form a Nx2 array, where is N is grid**2
lonlat = np.column_stack((lon.ravel(),lat.ravel()))

# Get the distances and get the argmin across the entire N length
idx = scipy.spatial.distance.cdist(lonlat,points).argmin(0)

# Get the indices corresponding to grid's shape as the final output
ind = np.column_stack((np.unravel_index(idx,lon.shape))).tolist()
```

Sample run -

```
In [161]: lon
Out[161]: 
array([[-11.   ,  -7.82 ,  -4.52 ,  -1.18 ,   2.19 ],
       [-12.   ,  -8.65 ,  -5.21 ,  -1.71 ,   1.81 ],
       [-13.   ,  -9.53 ,  -5.94 ,  -2.29 ,   1.41 ],
       [-14.1  ,  -0.04 ,  -6.74 ,  -2.91 ,   0.976]])

In [162]: lat
Out[162]: 
array([[-11.2  ,  -7.82 ,  -4.51 ,  -1.18 ,   2.19 ],
       [-12.   ,  -8.63 ,  -5.27 ,  -1.71 ,   1.81 ],
       [-13.2  ,  -9.52 ,  -5.96 ,  -2.29 ,   1.41 ],
       [-14.3  ,  -0.06 ,  -6.75 ,  -2.91 ,   0.973]])

In [163]: lonlat = np.column_stack((lon.ravel(),lat.ravel()))

In [164]: idx = scipy.spatial.distance.cdist(lonlat,points).argmin(0)

In [165]: np.column_stack((np.unravel_index(idx,lon.shape))).tolist()
Out[165]: [[0, 4], [0, 4], [0, 4], [0, 4], [0, 4], [0, 4], [3, 3]]
```

Runtime tests -

Define functions:

```
def find_indices(lon,lat,x,y):
    lonlat = np.dstack([lon,lat])
    delta = np.abs(lonlat-[x,y])
    ij_1d = np.linalg.norm(delta,axis=2).argmin()
    i,j = np.unravel_index(ij_1d,lon.shape)
    return i,j

def loopy_app(lon,lat,pts):
    return [find_indices(lon,lat,pts[i,0],pts[i,1]) for i in range(pts.shape[0])]

def vectorized_app(lon,lat,points):
    lonlat = np.column_stack((lon.ravel(),lat.ravel()))
    idx = scipy.spatial.distance.cdist(lonlat,points).argmin(0)
    return np.column_stack((np.unravel_index(idx,lon.shape))).tolist()
```

Timings:

```
In [179]: lon = np.random.rand(100,100)

In [180]: lat = np.random.rand(100,100)

In [181]: points = np.random.rand(50,2)

In [182]: %timeit loopy_app(lon,lat,points)
10 loops, best of 3: 47 ms per loop

In [183]: %timeit vectorized_app(lon,lat,points)
10 loops, best of 3: 16.6 ms per loop
```

For squeezing out more performance, [`np.concatenate`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html) could be used in place of [`np.column_stack`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.column_stack.html).

Answer (score 0):

Based on [@Cong Ma's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32909703/5446749), I have found the following solution:

```
def find_indices(points,lon,lat,tree=None):
    if tree is None:
        lon,lat = lon.T,lat.T
        lonlat = np.column_stack((lon.ravel(),lat.ravel()))
        tree = sp.spatial.cKDTree(lonlat)
    dist,idx = tree.query(points,k=1)
    ind = np.column_stack(np.unravel_index(idx,lon.shape))
    return [(i,j) for i,j in ind]
```

To put this solution and also the one from [Divakar's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32922456/5446749) into perspective, here are some timings of the function in which I am using `find_indices` (and where it's the bottleneck in terms of speed):

```
spatial_contour_frequency/pil0                :   331.9553
spatial_contour_frequency/pil1                :   104.5771
spatial_contour_frequency/pil2                :     2.3629
spatial_contour_frequency/pil3                :     0.3287
```

`pil0` is my initial approach, `pil1` Divakar's, and `pil2`/`pil3` the final solution above, where the tree is created on-the-fly in `pil2` (i.e. for every iteration of the loop in which `find_indices` is called) and only once in `pil3` (see [other thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32845601/count-how-often-each-field-point-is-inside-a-contour) for details). Even though Divakar's refinement of my initial approach gives me a 3x speed-up, cKDTree takes this to a whole new level with another 50x speedup! And moving the creation of the tree out of the function makes things even faster.

---

<sub>This answer was posted as an [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/32909087/5) to the question [Efficiently find indices of nearest points on non-rectangular 2D grid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32909087/efficiently-find-indices-of-nearest-points-on-non-rectangular-2d-grid) by the OP [flotzilla](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4419816/flotzilla) under CC BY-SA 3.0.</sub>